# Hairy ball theorem: references to applications

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, topological-vector-spaces, geometric-topology

I'm looking for references to applications of the Hairy ball theorem.

I already visited wikipedia and cited references, but I need a little more explanation in both meteorology and applications in computer graphics. If any other application would be excellent.

I've also read some questions on this site and some articles uploaded (an article of John Milnor for example), but none deals specifically with applications.

Maybe it's a bit difficult because I seek not know much about meteorology or computer graphics, but I'm just interested

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should search for "tokamak" and "hairy ball theorem". I've just seen this mentioned in Dundas' [Differential Topology](http://www.math.uib.no/~dundas/dt/080627dt.pdf) (page 88) but he leaves out the details.

Comment: @M.B +1 I had not thought magnetic fields but a lot of sense, good to know, thanks!

Comment: There's not that much detail to add. See p.13 in [these slides](https://spc.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/crpp/files/Enseignement/mhdcourse_JG_2012.pdf) for instance. Basically you want the [Lorentz force density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Continuous_charge_distribution) to be non-zero everywhere on the surface so that it can balance the plasma pressure by itself (in a static model).